# How to set value number only or the text input must have @ in text input React NATIVE

Tags: react-native, textinput

I want to make text input for phone number and the value must be number only and with minimum length 7, and another text input is for email, the value must have'@'. and if phone and email text input value not suitable with that condition, I want to give some alert.

```js
<Text
  style={{
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 0,
    textAlign: 'auto',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }}>
  Phone Number :
</Text>

<Item>
  <Input
    placeholder=""
    style={{ fontSize: 14, borderColor: '#00468c', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 8 }}
    placeholderTextColor='#cfcfcf'
    onChangeText={valueNoHP => {
      this.setState({ valueNoHP })
      console.log("Ini: " + valueNoHP)
    }}
    value={this.state.valueNoHP}
    keyboardType='number-pad'
    minLength={7}
  />
</Item>

<Text
  style={{
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 0,
    textAlign: 'auto',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }}>
  Email Address :
</Text>

<Item>
  <Input autoCapitalize='none' placeholder="" style={{ fontSize: 14, borderColor: '#00468c', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 8 }} placeholderTextColor='#cfcfcf'
    onChangeText={valueEmail => this.setState({ valueEmail })}
    value={this.state.valueEmail}
    keyboardType='email-address'
  />
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In onChangeText u can put in any function. So u can check the length with standard javascript stuff. As a design standpoint it is probably easier to have only 1 function that is called both onChangeText that check after the state is set.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to react-native **TextInput** doc here is the link, you will find a lot properties and methods which may help for future.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

Here is the working example that actually want to need. link is  to expo

https://snack.expo.io/@asad_4561/textinput?session_id=snack-session-7_eZSvZUo&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=33hlricz7f&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=TextInput&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true

code is here (you may change according to your need)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text,TextInput,Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class  App extends Component{ 
  constructor(props) 
  {
      super(props);
      this.FocusToPhone = null;
      this.FocusToEmail = null; 
      this.state={
        phone:0,
        email:"",
      };
  }
  onChangeEmail(text){
    this.setstate({email:text});
  }
  onChangephone(text){
    if(text.length < 7)
    {
      Alert.alert ('Alert', 'Phone number length is too small! please re-enter phone number');
      this.FocusToPhone.focus();
    }
    else
    {
      this.setstate({phone:text });
      this.FocusToEmail.focus();
    }  
  }
render()
    {
return (
    <View>
        <Text
      style={{
        marginTop: 10,
        marginLeft: 0,
        textAlign: 'auto',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}>
      Phone Number :
    </Text>
        <TextInput
          ref={(input) => { this.FocusToPhone = input; }}
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray',borderWidth: 1 }}
          onSubmitEditing={e => this.onChangephone(e.nativeEvent.text)}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
          keyboardType={"phone-pad"}
          placeholder="Phone #"
        />

    <Text
    style={{
      marginTop: 10,
      marginLeft: 0,
      textAlign: 'auto',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }}>
    Email Address :
  </Text>
        <TextInput
         ref={(input) => { this.FocusToEmail = input; }}
          placeholder="Email"
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray',borderWidth: 1 }}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
          onChangeText={text => this.onChangeEmail(text)}
          //value={value}
          keyboardType={"email-address"}
        />

    </View>

  );
}

}
```